# Crop Head and Upper Body from a live webcam feed

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, video, arkit, arcore

I am looking for ways of cropping the head and upper body contour form a live camera feed and putting it in front of a virtual background. For example how does zoom achieve this exact same thing with Virtual Background feature?

I know openCV is there, but I don't know there is just face detection or it can help with cropping the whole head and body including head hair, shoulders, arms etc.

I am not sure how apps like Instagram does it, but I know they have the functionality to replace the complete background of camera feed with virtual things. Not sure if they use ARKit or ARCore, but even these platforms only support detecting different positions on the face, nothing for detecting the boundary of the body itself.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Amit.

Answer (score 2):

Apps like Instagram and Snapchat use their own custom programs to achieve that like [SparkAR](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/) in Instagram case and [Lens Studio](https://lensstudio.snapchat.com/) for Snapchat. I really believe they don't use ARKit or ARCore, for stability reasons.

Now, If you are building your own program to detect face or background than you would ideally start with OpenCV. Then, over the top of it you would use MATLAB for calculating boundary, head or whatever you want to achieve.